# Forecasting with two separate periods of time

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a sales forecasting problem where I only have three months of year 2018 ( Jan, fev, march) and three months of year 2019 (oct, nov,dec) and I have to forecast the sales for all the months of 2020.
I am new with the forecasting problems and what I can conclude from these data that it is time series data but it's so limited and the gap between the two years is about 18 months so handling missing data won't be a solution for this. I have been so stack can anyone help me please.
Can you suggest me what to do ?

Comment: It will be almost impossible to build any sort of time series forecasting model to predict an entire year's worth of data with only these six data points. You need more data. There is **no** way to construct this model with any degree of accuracy.

Comment: And the problem that these six points are not from the same year ..

Comment: it's a use case that I have to resolve it and I cant have more data..

Comment: All I have is two intervals of time one contains the three first months of 2018 and the other one is the three years of 2019 and I am requested to forecast 2020..

Comment: You will not be able to create a reasonable model given these parameters.